# Jackson deserialization - ignore root property

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm developing client library and API response that service returns looks something like this:

`{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "currentState": "MY_STATE",
        "links": [
            ...
        ]
    }
}`

I have following Java Pojo which should be mapped to `data` attribute:

`@Value
    @JsonRootName("data")
    public class UserStateDto {
        private UserStateName currentState;
        private List<Map<String, Object>> links;
    }`

And my object mapper has configuration to unwrap root element: `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`

But deserialization fails because there is `status` attribute on root level which is not mapped and I'm getting following exception:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'status' does not match expected ('data') for type [simple type, class ....UserStateDto]`

Is it possible to somehow ignore root level properties? Basically what I want to achieve is to deserialize only `data` attribute. I would like to avoid introducing additional Java POJO wrapper on top of it.

Comment: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`
or
`@JsonIgnoreProperties("{myUnknownProperty}")`
try this

Comment: Tried both. Unfortunately those do not work in this case :(

Comment: try configuring object mapper for `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`.
`objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`